# want to find the average length of audio in a bunch of audio files in a loop

Tags: librosa

Using this code for the same its working But how to display the  average length of these audio files, also how to find maximum and minimum duration files?

```
import librosa

import glob
import librosa

path=glob.glob('E:/...*/*.wav') 
for i in range(len(path)) :
    y, sr = librosa.load(path[i], sr=16000)
    z=librosa.get_duration(y)
    Z=Z+z

Z/len(path)
```

Comment: Your code is not working. Only the duration of the last file is stored in z, so whatever that is will be reported as the "average".

Comment: Thats what I am asking , how to average the length of all audio files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use code such as this. Using `get_duration(filename=...)` makes it work without having to load the files, which is much faster. Here we use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to loop over paths and collect all the durations into a list.

```py
import glob
import librosa
import numpy

paths = glob.glob('E:/...*/*.wav')
durations = [ librosa.get_duration(filename=p) for p in paths ]

stats = {
    'mean': numpy.mean(durations),
    'max': numpy.max(durations),
    'min': numpy.min(durations),
}

print(stats)
```